# Adding extra commands inbetween xargs commands

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, xargs

I have a bash script like the following example that attempts to first list a bunch of items, then run a command on those items individually:

```
customListCommand | xargs -P 10 -n1 echo
```

If customListCommand returns the following output:

```
a
b
c
```

Then what I have with xargs will essentially perform:

```
echo a
echo b
echo c
```

In addition to this, I would like to add a "sleep" to the xargs command so that it runs after each echo, in this manner:

```
echo a
sleep 1
echo b
sleep 1
echo c
sleep 1
```

Is it possible to do this for the xargs expression? I presume adding an additional pipe at the end will not work since that might pipe the output of all the echos before doing a single sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like that??

```
customListCommand | xargs -P 10 -n1 bash -c 'echo "$0"; sleep 1'
```

It should basically do the job for you. Please let me.know if more help is required!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use this:

```
customListCommand | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo {}; sleep 1'
```

Comment: This should really be `bash -c 'echo "$1"; sleep 1' _ {}` as direct injection into the bash command is a security vulnerability.